# Reading JSON child object

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have the following JSON Content:

```
{
    "query": {
        "pages": {
            "7931046": {
                "pageid": 7931046,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Tang Aidi",
                "revisions": [
                    {
                        "contentformat": "text/x-wiki",
                        "contentmodel": "wikitext",
                        "*": "SOME TEXT"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I try to read the "SOME TEXT" String from it.

I am stuck already when trying to read the "pages" object. I guess it should be a JSONObject but it throws me

```
JSONObject["pages"] not found
```

with following code:

```
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(sEntireContent);
            JSONObject oParse=(JSONObject) obj.get("query");
            //JSONArray oPages=oParse.getJSONArray("pages");
>>>>>>>>>>  JSONObject oPages=(JSONObject) obj.get("pages");
            JSONObject firstPage=(JSONObject) oPages.get(0);
            JSONObject oRevisions=(JSONObject) firstPage.get("revisions");
            sWikitext=oRevisions.getString ("*");
```

I then firther don't know how to read a childobject, from which I don't know the name. In my example the "7931046" is a random/sequence number

Comment: What JSON library are you using to parse with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a JSONObject has one or more unknown keys as child elements, you can iterate through them like so:

```
JSONObject pages = obj.get("pages");
Iterator iterator = pages.keys();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    String key = (String)iterator.next();
    JSONObject page = pages.getJSONObject(key);

    //do stuff with the page...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Go for relative to the parent

JSONObject oPages = oParse.getJSONObject("pages");

Comment: Yes of course. You are right. I am so stupid :-) Gave Up 1. I am not sure to whom I should accept the answer at the moment.